# can't log in to Ubuntu using the correct password

Tags: virtualbox, password

I am trying to log to my Linux Ubuntu with the correct password, but it is always say:
"sorry, that didn't work, please try again"
I am doing this 7-8 tries sometimes until it is log in.
What is wrong with this os?
How can I solve this?
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on VirtualBox on windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI:  Your provided details imply you've not applied security fixes/upgrade since before early August-2020 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO date of 18.04.5, but installed systems upgraded before that date, and fully upgraded systems show 18.04.6 currently), and you didn't specify what Ubuntu 18.04 product; Server? Desktop? but it reaches EOSS five years after launch in 2018-April (18.04) which is only days away now, so I'd suggest planning an upgrade - or re-install given how *unmaintained* it is given your provided details.

Comment: I work on Ubuntu desktop.  It seems that I can't upgrade to further versions because Petalinux- Xilinx software I uses - works only until 18.04.4 version  :https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2020.2-English/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide/Installation-Requirements

Comment: Can someone suggest other workaround to solve this annoying, time consuming thing? Why password is needed at all if i am the only user?